# Upgrading code that uses OpenCV2.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to upgrade python code that was programed for OpenCV 2.4 to be used with OpenCV 3.3.
I found a problem with the flags of the function cv2.calcCovarMatrix, as I show next.

The code is this one:

```
# Compute 3x3 covariance matrix
covar, mean = cv2.calcCovarMatrix(total_matrix, cv2.cv.CV_COVAR_NORMAL | cv2.cv.CV_COVAR_SCALE | cv2.cv.CV_COVAR_ROWS)
```

The error that raises is this one:

```
covar, mean = cv2.calcCovarMatrix(total_matrix, cv2.cv.CV_COVAR_NORMAL | cv2.cv.CV_COVAR_SCALE | cv2.cv.CV_COVAR_ROWS) 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'
```

The python version is 2.7

Does anyone know a way of upgrade this particular piece of code? I think the problem is that the flags now have a different name, but I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

From OpenCV 2.X OpenCV 3.0 a few things [changed](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0).

Specifically:

cv2.cv doesn't exists in OpenCV 3.0. Use simply cv2.

So you need to change to:

```
covar, mean = cv2.calcCovarMatrix(total_matrix, cv2.CV_COVAR_NORMAL | cv2.CV_COVAR_SCALE | cv2.CV_COVAR_ROWS)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tryed that before asking here, maybe I shoud have added the information in the post.

If I execute the function like that the error that raises is:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_COVAR_NORMAL'

Since I need the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors I tryed also with PCACompute, but it discards de eigenvalues.